# Saving a streamed or buffered audio file to documents folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to save an audio file to the documents folder while/after its playing. Buffering file format is mp3. (Better if its possible to download the audio file realtime while its playing/buffering)

I did search a lot on the internet, but couldn't found a tutorial or sample code specifically for this requirement.

This is how I am buffering the mp3

```
NSString *strMessageUrl = @"https://example.com/example.mp3";

NSLog(@"Url %@", strMessageUrl);

NSURL *audioUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:strMessageUrl];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.btnPause setHidden:NO];
[appDelegate.btnPlay setHidden:YES];
appDelegate.moviePlayer.contentURL=audioUrl;
appDelegate.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[appDelegate.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[appDelegate.moviePlayer play];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a url directly to an actual file, you can simply create an NSURLRequest and save it to disk asynchronously at the same time you start the player.

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://example.com/example.mp3"]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (data && connectionError != nil) {
        NSString *filePath = @"documentDirectory/example.mp3";
        if([data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
            //keep track of filePath
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong!");
    }
}];
```